# Can't choose which HDD to boot from. Old drive not showing up in msconfig boot tab

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bootable-media, disk-cloning, msconfig

I have attached an image that shows my system information, my disk management, and my msconfig boot tab. This is very weird to me: previous versions of Windows allowed me to enter a menu at startup that gave a choice of which devices to boot from.

But none of the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys do anything, and there is no option for that in advanced startup options when I reboot using `shutdown /r /o /t 0` or when I hold shift and click restart. I have just cloned my old 250GB hard drive to the new 1TB hard drive. For some reason, it decided to start booting from the 1TB drive, which is what I wanted but it's a little disconcerting that I didn't tell it to. And now the old drive, while still showing up in disk management, isn't appearing as a bootable option in msconfig.

How do I choose which drive to boot from without disconnecting whichever drive I don't want to use—as that doesn't actually address the problems, themselves. I want to fully understand what's happening and why.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the choice when you start your system by setting it in System Properties. Use Windows + R key combo and type sysdm.cpl in the Run dialog then click OK. On System Properties, click the [image: Advanced tab]
Advanced tab, then click the Settings button and you can then set the [image: System Startup options] System Startup options.

Comment: So, there's only one option in "default operating system." Since one hard drive is a clone of the other, should I be surprised that there's only one operating system to choose from? I don't see anything that could help me choose between either drive.